# Could not load file or assembly 'Facebook.Web'

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I'm a newbie in C# and I encounters this error when I plot in the app ID, secret and URLs. What did I do wrong/miss out?

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Facebook.Web' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:

Line 22:       <httpHandlers>
Line 23:         <add verb="*" path="facebookredirect.axd" 
Line 24:                       type="Facebook.Web.FacebookAppRedirectHttpHandler, Facebook.Web" />
Line 25:       </httpHandlers>
Line 26:    </system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Facebook.Web.dll in the `bin` directory of your web application?

Comment: nope... do i just create a bin folder and copy the file from the release?

Comment: @jasonwcm: Pretty much, yeah. However if you're using VS, the web application project should take care of that for you.

Comment: i created a bin folder and copy Facebook.Web.dll into it.

Comment: @jasonwcm: ...and are you still getting the same error message?

Comment: im using visual web developer 2010 express. this is my first time using c sharp and im trying to build a FB canvas application. ive entered the app id, secret and urls in the web.config. what else do i need to do??

Comment: @jasonwcm: If you're entirely new to C# and ASP.NET, you might want to start by writing a few simple apps (with no integration into external things such as Facebook) to familiarize yourself with how things work.

Comment: yea im trying my best to get familiarized and while at the same time, i thought someone out here would be able to point me in the right direction. Thanks buddy. =)